# i am unable to ENABLE/DISABLE functions in function app programmatically. It does change my function.json file

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

```
    public class AzureFunctionsHelper
    {
        private static string azureFunctionURL = string.Empty;
        private static string azureFunctionUsername = string.Empty;
        private static string azureFunctionPassword = string.Empty;
        private static List<string> azureFunctionNames = new List<string>();
        private WebClient _webClient;

        public AzureFunctionsHelper()
        {
            if (azureFunctionURL == string.Empty || azureFunctionUsername == string.Empty || azureFunctionPassword == string.Empty)
            {
                setParameters();
            }

            _webClient = new WebClient
            {
                Headers = { ["ContentType"] = "application/json" },
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(azureFunctionUsername, azureFunctionPassword),
                BaseAddress = azureFunctionURL
            };
        }
        public void SetAzureFuncDisabled(bool isDisabled)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach(var functionName in azureFunctionNames)
                {
                    string conUri = _webClient.BaseAddress + $"/{functionName}/function.json";
                    var functionJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FunctionSettings>(_webClient.DownloadString(conUri));
                    functionJson.disabled = isDisabled;
                    _webClient.Headers["If-Match"] = "*";
                    _webClient.UploadString(conUri, "STOR", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(functionJson));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        private static string GetFunctionJsonUrl(string functionName)
        {
            try
            {
                return $"{functionName}/function.json";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        public void setParameters()
        {
            try
            {
                var filePath = Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "appsettings.json");

                azureFunctionURL = ReaderHelper.Read(filePath, "AzureFunctionAppURL");
                azureFunctionUsername = ReaderHelper.Read(filePath, "AzureFunctionUsername");
                azureFunctionPassword = ReaderHelper.Read(filePath, "AzureFunctionPassword");
                var values = ReaderHelper.Read(filePath, "AzureFunctionNames");
                azureFunctionNames = values.Split(", ").ToList();

    //It does change function.json file "IsDisabled" attribute from true to false but it does //not effect on my function status
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

//Classes

```
    internal class FunctionSettings
    {
        public string generatedBy { get; set; }
        public string configurationSource { get; set; }
        public List<Binding> bindings { get; set; }
        public bool disabled { get; set; }
        public string scriptFile { get; set; }
        public string entryPoint { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Binding
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public List<string> methods { get; set;}
        public string authLevel { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I create two function first is Timer trigger function and second is HTTP trigger function.

add a string value in `local.settings.json` .

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
      "Function_Disable": "True"
    }
}
```

Function 1 : add `Function_Disable` attributes. I try to disable this function1 function.
[image]

Function 2 : no change in another function.
[image]

**Output :-** function 1 disable
[image]

After remove `Function_Disable` attributes.
Function1
[image]

`local.settings.json` file
[image]

**Output:-** Show two function run.
[image]